# Timestamp difference between the values surrounding nulls BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to calculate timestamp difference between the values surrounding nulls in Column1 as resulting in ResultSeconds column:

```
WITH table1 AS (

  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:06 UTC' Datetime,  1.2 Column1,     NULL  ResultSeconds UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:16 UTC',           NULL,            NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:26 UTC',           NULL,            NULL  UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:36 UTC',           4.4,              30  UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:46 UTC',           2.1,             NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:00:56 UTC',           6.3,             NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:01:06 UTC',           NULL,            NULL  UNION ALL
  SELECT  '2020-12-01 00:01:16 UTC',           2.2,              20   
)  

select * from table1
```

I tried with LAG() and LEAD() but i was unsuccessful. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: '2020-12-01 00:00:66 UTC' is not a valid timestamp and if I understand the problem correctly, the second timestamp difference should be 10 seconds (as in the difference of '2020-12-01 00:01:06 UTC'  and  '2020-12-01 00:00:56 UTC')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, 
  if(not Column1 is null and lag(Column1) over(order by Datetime) is null,
    timestamp_diff(timestamp(Datetime), first_value(if(Column1 is null, null, timestamp(Datetime)) ignore nulls) over win, second),
    null
  ) result
from table1
window win as (order by Datetime desc rows between 1 following and unbounded following)
# order by Datetime
```

If applied to [corrected - 2020-12-01 00:00:66 UTC] sample data in your question - output is

[image]